# How to read bracket/colon style parameters specification in Angular API doc?

Tags: javascript, angular

For example in the Angular API's [CurrencyPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe) the parameters are specified like this:

```
{{ value_expression | currency [ : currencyCode [ : display [ : digitsInfo [ : locale ] ] ] ] }}
```

How to understand this complicated notation ? Why not simply list comma-separated parameters ?

Comment: It means that currency pipe can take 4 optional parameters and you can see all cases in usage notes https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe#usage-notes

Comment: adding to the above comment,... and not anyone is dependent on either, all are independent parameters. You can use either with pipe

Comment: Ok, my mistake was to read this as a method signature, while it is actually a template. Now it seems to me that they could have used the question mark `?` to specify optional parameters. Why using this `[:a[:b[:c]]]` instead of for ex. `a?, b?, c?`. It makes me think that ´b´ is somewhat included in ´a´ and so on.